# eigenvalues of integral matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

Is it possible that a $3$-by-$3$ matrix with integer values and determinant 1 has a real eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity 2, that is not equal to $\pm 1$?

Doing some elementary computations one can rephrase the question as follows. Do there exist integers $k$ and $m$ such that $a=\frac{1}{3}(k\pm \sqrt{k^2-3m})$ and  $b=\frac{1}{3}(k\mp 2\sqrt{k^2-3m})$ are real numbers and $a^2b=1$ but $a,b \neq \pm 1$?

Comment: Some motivation for the question would be nice.

Comment: Well, I wanted to conclude that a 3-by-3 matrix with integer values and determinant 1 is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$, when all its eigenvalues are real and different from $\pm 1$. Seems easy, but I just get lost in the equations...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no solution to your problem. The pattern of proof is familiar : we show that there cannot be a solution
with too large parameters, and then a finite numbers of cases remain to be checked
by exhaustive inspection.

If a solution matrix exists, it has eigenvalues $a,a,\frac{1}{a^2}$
for some real $a\not\in\lbrace -1,0,1\rbrace$. So its characteristic 
polynomial is

$$
\chi= (X-a)^2(X-\frac{1}{a^2})=
X^3-\frac{2a^3+1}{a^2}X^2+\frac{a^3+2}{a}X-1 \tag{1}
$$

Then $x=\frac{2a^3+1}{a^2}$ and $y=\frac{a^3+2}{a}$ must be integers. Eliminating $a$, we 
deduce  purely algebraically (computing resultants) that
$Q(x,y)=0$ where

$$
Q(x,y)=4y^3 - x^2y^2 - 18xy + 4x^3 + 27 \tag{2}
$$

**Lemma 1.** Suppose that $x \geq 17$. Then the univariate polynomial
$Q(x,.)$ has exactly three real roots $\rho_1 < \rho_2 < \rho_3 $ with
$\rho_i\in (\alpha_i,\beta_i)$, where 
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
\alpha_1=-\sqrt{4x-0.99} &,& \ \beta_1=-\sqrt{4x}, \\
\alpha_2=\sqrt{4x-0.99}&,& \ \beta_2=\sqrt{4x}, \\
\alpha_3=\frac{x^2}{4}&,& \ \beta_3=\frac{x^2+0.99}{4}\\
\end{array}
$$

**Corollary 2 (of Lemma 1).** There is no integer solution of $Q(x,y)=0$ with $x\geq 17$.

**Lemma 3.** Suppose that $x \leq -8$. Then the univariate polynomial
$Q(x,.)$ has exactly one real root $\rho \in (\alpha,\beta)$  where 
$\alpha=\frac{x^2-0.999}{2}$ and $\beta=\frac{x^2}{2}$.

**Corollary 4 (of Lemma 3).** There is no integer solution of $Q(x,y)=0$ with $x\leq -8$.

Once we have corollaries 2 and 4, all that remains to be done is check
the cases $x=(-7),(-6),(-5), \ldots ,8$ one by one. Inspection reveals
that for these values, $Q(x,.)$ has rational roots only when $x=(-1),3$ or $5$. 
For $x=5$, the rational root is $\frac{17}{4}$, a noninteger. Too bad ...

**Proof of Lemma 1.** If $x$ is $\geq 17$, the number $|\alpha_1|$ is 
$\geq \sqrt{4\times 17+0.99}\geq 8.1$, so $a=|\alpha_1|-8.1$ is nonnegative.
Also, the number $\alpha_2$ is $\geq \sqrt{4\times 17-0.99}\geq 8.15$, so $b=\alpha_2-8.15$ is nonnegative. Also, $\beta_3 \geq \frac{17^2+0.99}{4} 
\times 72$. Finally, $c=x-17$ is nonnegative.

$$
\begin{array}{lclc}
Q(x,\alpha_1)&=&-\frac{99}{1600}a^4 - \frac{6019}{4000}a^3 - \frac{30213}{2500}a^2 
- \frac{7117389}{200000}a - \frac{6956739}{4000000} & <0 \\
& &  &   \\
Q(x,\beta_1)&=&\frac{|\beta_1|^3}{2}+27 & >0 \\
& &  &   \\
Q(x,\alpha_2)&=& \frac{99}{1600}b^4 + \frac{12137}{8000}b^3 + \frac{4018197}{320000}b^2 
+ \frac{20410041}{640000}b + \frac{12365891}{10240000} & >0 \\
& &  &   \\
Q(x,\beta_2)&=&-\frac{\beta_2^3}{2}+27 & <0 \\
& &  &   \\
Q(x,\alpha_3)&=& -\frac{x^3}{2}+27 & <0 \\
& &  &   \\
Q(x,\beta_3)&=& \frac{99}{1600}c^4 + \frac{1483}{400}c^3 + \frac{6553101}{80000}c^2 + \frac{31287117}{40000}c 
+ \frac{43169498099}{16000000} & >0 \\
& &  &   \\
\end{array}
$$

The intermediate value property then yields three roots for our degree three polynomial, 
and concludes the proof of the lemma.

**Proof of Corollary 2.** If there is an integer solution $(x,y)$, then $y$ must be one
of $\rho_1,\rho_2,\rho_3$. If, for example, $y=\rho_1$, then $y^2-4x$ in an integer in
$(0,1)$, which is impossible. The other cases are similar.

**Proof of Lemma 3.**

If $x$ is $\leq -8$, the number $d=|x|-8$ is nonnegative. Then

$$
\begin{array}{lclc}
Q(x,\alpha)&=&-\frac{999}{16000}d^4 - \frac{749}{500}d^3 - \frac{94809999}{8000000}d^2 - 
\frac{17185749}{500000}d - \frac{12580874999}{16000000000} & <0 \\
& &  &   \\
Q(x,\beta)&=&\frac{|x|^3}{2}+27 & >0 \\
& &  &   \\
\end{array}
$$

So we have a root $\rho\in(\alpha,\beta)$. Computing
$$\frac{Q(x,y)}{y-\rho}=
4y^2+(4\rho-x^2)y+(4\rho^2-18x-\rho x^2)
$$
and the discriminant of this trinomial in $y$ is $x^4+8\rho x^2 + 288x - 48\rho^2 < 0$,
so $\rho$ is the only root.

**Proof of Corollary 4.** This is similar to, and simpler than, the proof of corollary
2.

Answer (score 6):

As in Ewan's proof, write
$$x = \frac{2 a^3+1}{a^2} \quad y = \frac{a^3+2}{a}.$$
Notice that
$$a = \frac{xy-9}{2 (x^2-3y)}. \quad (\ast)$$
So, if $x$ and $y$ are integers then either $a$ is rational or else $xy=9$ and $x^2=3y$. The latter case implies $x (x^2/3) = 9$, so $x=y=3$ and $a=1$, which we already ruled out.

So we focus on the case where $a$ is rational. Write $a=p/q$ in lowest terms. So
$$x = \frac{2p^3+q^3}{p^2 q} \quad y=\frac{p^3+2 q^3}{p q^2}.$$
From the formula for $x$, any prime that divides $p$ also divides $q$; from the formula $y$, any prime that divides $q$ also divides $p$. Since $p/q$ is in lowest terms, we get $a = \pm 1$.

So, where did $(\ast)$ come from? Since the map $a \mapsto \left( \frac{2a^3+1}{a^2}, \frac{a^3+2}{a} \right)$ is generically injective, the subfield of $k(a)$  generated by $(2a^3+1)/a^2$ and $(a^3+2)/a$ should be all of $k(a)$. So such a formula should exist, and I just needed to find it. To find it, I used that $a$ is double root of $t^3-x t^2+y t - 1$, so it is also a root of $3 t^2 - 2x t + y$. Therefore, $a$ is a root of $(t^3-x t^2+y t - 1) - (t/3 - x/9) (3 t^2 - 2x t + y) = (2y/3 - 2x^2/9) t +(xy/9 -1)$. I solved this equation for $t$.